# Android MAT: activities being held by java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to track down some unexpectedly high memory usage.
I've reduced the complexity of my app and as it is currently I have a main activity with a button. Pressing this buttons starts a new activity with a videoView that plays a video. When the video finishes playing or it's dismissed by a close button, the activity is stopped and the user is returned back to the main activity.

Now the strangeness (well strange to me). When the app first launches it sits at about 20mb memory usage. Each time the video activity is started, closed and returned the memory usage increases by ~6mb. But this is not a leak as it will continue to increase to about 50mb or so then drop down to ~30mb. Then it will grow and drop between 50mb and 30mb.

I made a dump with MAT and in the histogram view saw that there were multiple video Activities still around when I was expecting none or at worse one. On subsequent dumps it looks like the number of instances bounces between 1-5 (corresponding to the low and high mem values).

I'm not sure what to do next! I'm new to MAT and don't know how to use it to track down whats happening. When I do a merge_shortest_path excluding weak references it points to class java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference as the one holding all the memory. I googled around and checked none of my code overrides any finalize methods.

So is this normal or does anyone have any clue as to why my video activities are not being cleared right away when they're done.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

KK